# Using Animation in Adapter with ViewHolder Pattern

Tags: android

I have a problem when using an Animation in my Adapter.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.newRoomView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.newRoom);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Room item = items.get(position);

        // animate new rooms
        if (item.isNewRoom()) {
            AlphaAnimation alphaAnim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
            alphaAnim.setDuration(1500);
            alphaAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    holder.newRoomView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            });
            holder.newRoomView.startAnimation(alphaAnim);
        }

        // ...

        return convertView;
    }
```

When adding a new room outside of the adapter and calling `notifyDataSetChanged` the new room is correctly animated, but when `onAnimationEnd` is called, another (not new room) is hidden.

Is there any way to get the correct room hidden?

Comment: why dont you try it using `RecyclerView`?

Comment: post your item's layout, plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't declared the `holder` variable in the `getView()` method, I can only assume that you've declared it as an instance variable in your class. This is your problem. By the time the animation is completed, the variable `holder` is holding a reference to a completely different item.

You need to use a local variable which is declared as `final` inside the `getView()` method. I don't know if you need this `holder` variable outside the `getView()` method or not, but if you do, you can do this:

```
    // animate new rooms
    if (item.isNewRoom()) {
        final ViewHolder holderCopy = holder; // make a copy
        AlphaAnimation alphaAnim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
        alphaAnim.setDuration(1500);
        alphaAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                holderCopy.newRoomView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        });
        holder.newRoomView.startAnimation(alphaAnim);
    }
```

This, of course, will not work if the animation takes so long that the view has been recycled in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (item.isNewRoom()) {

        // store view reference first
        final View newRoomView = holder.newRoomView;
        ...
        alphaAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                // hide exactly this view when animation ends
                newRoomView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due of the recycling mechanism of the ListView. Try tagging the animated view and use `findViewByTag` to retrieve it `onAnimationEnd`. E.g.

```
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.newRoomView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.newRoom);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Room item = items.get(position);

    // animate new rooms
    if (item.isNewRoom()) {
        AlphaAnimation alphaAnim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
        alphaAnim.setDuration(1500);
        alphaAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                View view = convertView.findViewWithTag(position);
                if (view != null) {
                     view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } 

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        });
        holder.newRoomView.startAnimation(alphaAnim);
        holder.newRoomView.setTag(position);
    }

    // ...

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to migrate to the new [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html), you will be able to use this great animation library, check it out: https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind you need to always have an else statement for things like this.
Otherwise anything else using the same view holder will also go invisible.

```
if (item.isNewRoom()) {
        AlphaAnimation alphaAnim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
        alphaAnim.setDuration(1500);
        alphaAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                holder.newRoomView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        });
        holder.newRoomView.startAnimation(alphaAnim);
    }else{
        holder.newRoomView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. I have had this issue before, and this is probably an Android bug:

You are using inner objects to set the animation listener:

```
 alphaAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){/*bla bla bla*/});
```

Change the above code to something like this:

```
AnimationListener myListener = new AnimationListener(){/*bla bla bla*/};
alphaAnim.setAnimationListener(myListener);
```

Pretty crazy a solution, I know, but it has saved my ass in several similar occasions.

Comment: This answer is useless. The code you have suggested is exactly the same as the code you are replacing. You are still creating an anonymous class, the same as before. The compiler will compile both code snippets to exactly the same thing.

Comment: @David Wasser: This has worked for me in the past. Are you 100% sure that the codes will be exactly the same on Android?

Comment: Yes. Exactly the same. I can't believe that this solved any problem you may have had in the past.

Comment: I had the same exact problem as OP. But since you are a much more seasoned programmer, i will remove my answer as soon as I get to my PC.